# How to get the age from birth date in nodejs

Tags: node.js, date

I am creating an api where i am entering the user details, i want to calculate the age when user add date of birth, here is what i am doing

```
  var age
  var today = new Date();
  var birthday=Date(req.body.DOB)//here i am getting the dob value 
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthday.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthday.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    console.log("getage ", age);
```

`var birthday=Date(req.body.DOB)` i am getting the value on here `req.body.DOB` but it is giving me `InvalidDate` on `birthday` variable and my `DOB` variable type is `String`

and it is sending this error too `TypeError: birthday.getFullYear is not a function`

kindly help how to do this.

Comment: What is the value recieved in `req.body.DOB`?

Comment: In line 3, I think it's supposed to be `new Date(req.body.DOB)` instead of `Date(req.body.DOB)`

Comment: a date, like this ```12-09-2002```

Comment: @PyxlDavon it is still sending me InvalidDate

Comment: i changed DOB type to Date, but still same error

Answer (score 1):

You can use an npm package age-calculator https://www.npmjs.com/package/age-calculator
it works pretty well I am using it in my project, with it you can use moment https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment to formate date as required. I am also adding sample code

```
const moment = require('moment')

//Calculate Age Modules
let { AgeFromDateString } = require('age-calculator');

var date = "27-10-2001"
var EditedDob = moment(data, "DD-MM-YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD')

//console.log(EditedDob)

let ageFromString = new AgeFromDateString(EditedDob).age;
```

Feel free to revert back in case of any query.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i want to resolve this without using package!

Answer (score 1):

i use this method to solve this problem

```
var dob = req.body.DOB;
    var datesplit=dob.split('-');
    var year = datesplit[2]
    var month = datesplit[1]
    var day = datesplit[0]
    var age = today.getFullYear() - year;
    if (today.getMonth() < month || (today.getMonth() == month && today.getDate() < day)) {
      age--;
    }
```